# Magento 2 - Add custom attribute to layout container

Tags: magento2, layout

I try to add a new container to my layout. The container needs the attribute `data-block='minicart'`

```
<container name="minicart-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="minicart-wrapper" data-block='minicart'/>
```

If I try this I get

> **Element 'container', attribute 'data-block': The attribute 'data-block' is not allowed.**

More Code:

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
    <container name="header-row" label="Header Bootstrap" as="header-row" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row">

        <container name="header-row-col-a" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-2"/>
        <container name="header-row-col-b" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-7"/>
        <container name="header-row-col-c" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-3">

            <container name="minicart-row" label="Wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row no-gutters minicart-wrapper">  <--- Need data-block="minicart" here

                <container name="mini-wk" label="Top" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-9 offset-3 mini-wk">

                    <container name="mini-wk-top" label="Top" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="mini-wk-top">
                        <container name="mini-wk-top-row" label="Top Row" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row no-gutters">

                            <container name="mini-wk-top-row-col-a" label="Benutzerkonto" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-6"/>
                            <container name="mini-wk-top-row-col-b" label="Anmelden/Abmelden" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-6"/>
                        </container>
                    </container>

                    <container name="mini-wk-content" label="Minicart-Main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="mini-wk-content row no-gutters"/>
                </container>
            </container>
        </container>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in core Magento 2, the `container` node only supports these attributes:

- name
- label
- before
- after
- as
- output
- htmlTag
- htmlId
- htmlClass

You would need to load a template inside that container and add your attribute there.

Answer (score 0):

You should Try

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="Vendor_ModuleName::css/style.css"/>
</head>
   <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="new-class-name"/>
        <attribute name="data-block" value="minicart"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

**[Update answer for add attribute ]**

use jQuery to add attibute to your container

*please use container class name to add atrribute*

```
$('.minicart-wrapper').attr("data-block", "minicart");
```

***I hope it helps you***

Comment: @BenCrook is right here is alternative way to do

Comment: Why update handle `customer_account` ?

Comment: @Black this is used in Customer Dashboard. Here it's not Require. I update my Answer.

Comment: I don't understand. How is this code supposed to add the attribute `data-block` to my container with name `minicart-wrapper` ?

Comment: @Black  BenCrook already said It's not possible in Magento , Here I am show add attribute in Main Body Tag of This Layout only , and other is You would need to load a template inside that container and add your attribute there.

Comment: "You would need to load a template inside that container and add your attribute there"
This does not work in my case, since I need the attribute on the outer container.

Comment: @Black can you share your code more  ?

Comment: I added more code

Comment: @Black now another way is jQuery,answer is Update, if have a any doubt ask here

Comment: Maybe it works if I call it in the right place before the main script is fired. I will try

Comment: @Black let me know the above solution is working or not for you?

Comment: I will let you know, but I have no time at the moment to test it :/

Answer (score 0):

So there's not really a good way to solve this but it is duable.

If you must add a new attribute to a container or block you will need to modify the file:`vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/etc/elements.xsd`

Here we will want to look for the type of tag you are wanting to modify.

***ex.*** if i wanted to change a reference container i'd look for `containerReferenceType` under this section you'll find an `<xs:attribute` in this area is where you want to define your attribute.

I recommend doing this via patch as this makes it easier to maintain the modification through entire project without the need of changing the `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` to point to the path of YOUR .xsd file. As this might get tricky later on down the road if you find yourself needing this attribute in other parts of your project.